# Как устроено iocp в System.Net.Socket?

Tags: c#, .net

Как IOCP устроено в нативе - понятно. Создается IO порт, к нему привязываются сокеты. Запускается несколько потоков с GetQueuedCompletionStatus, которые и обрабатывают пакеты. Отправляются запросы с сокетов на подключения к серверам.

1) Но как это реализовано в дотнете? Ведь мы не видим никакого аналога GetQueuedCompletionStatus или чего то подобного. Мы не видим самого IO порта. Мы работаем с асинхронными сокетами - как с синхронными. Вообще сколько портов IO используются на какое колл-во сокетов? Всего один или несколько? Сколько потоков обрабатывают пакеты с помощью GetQueuedCompletionStatus?

2) Что конкретно делает опция [Socket.UseOnlyOverlappedIO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.useonlyoverlappedio(v=vs.110).aspx)? Написано только, что она принуждает сокет работать только в IO режиме. Но тогда резонный вопрос, какой режим сокета используется если не выставить эту опцию? Синхронный? Неблокируемый? RIO (хотя о чем я говорю, рио еще не допилили)...

p.s. извините за такое колл-во вопросов, но информации по этому аспекту действительно почти нету.

Comment: 2) Если документация не говорит, какой режим выставляется без этой опции, логично предположить, что в этом случае нужный режим выбирает фреймворк на своё усмотрение (и не обязательно всегда одинаковым образом).

Comment: @VladD, именно поэтому я и задал вопрос. Я столкнулся с определенными проблемами, при портировании кода с натива на дотнет. А именно - проблемами производительности большого колл-ва сокетов. Просто так я бы не полез в эту тематику, если бы все устраивало. Чтобы понять суть проблемы - нужно понимать алгоритм работы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В пуле потоков есть отдельный поток, который занимается ожиданием на IOCP.

Когда вы вызываете BeginReceive, он [начинает с подготовки структуры OverlappedAsyncResult](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L4284) путем вызова его метода [SetUnmanagedStructures](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/_OverlappedAsyncResult.cs#L103). На этом этапе .NET Framework определяет какой метод будет использоваться для получения результата - IOCP (начиная с WinNT) или обычный асинхронный вызов (Win9x). Непосредственный выбор способа происходит в базовом классе [BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.cs в строке 158](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/4fe4349175f4c5091d972a7e56ea12012f1e7170/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/_BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.cs#L158).

Если система решила использовать IOCP - у сокета вызывается метод [BindToCompletionPort](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L7547). В новых фреймворках он вызывает внешний метод `ThreadPool.BindHandle(m_Handle);`, реализация которого выложена в общий доступ только для coreclr, подробности можно видеть в файле [win32threadpool.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp).

Но есть и .NET-реализация через P/Invoke, которая сейчас отключена директивами условной компиляции. Ее можно увидеть на referencesource в классе [SocketThreadPool](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L9983).

Начинать изучать ее можно с функции [ThreadPoolFunc()](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs#L10065). Как видно из нее, в пуле потоков существует один или несколько IO-потоков, ждущих на общем для всех сокетов IOCP и вызывающих колбеки.

Comment: Благодарю за хороший ответ. Теперь понятно, почему .NET так сильно уступает нативу на большом колл-ве сокетов. Вы не знаете, существует ли способ увечить колл-во IO портов?

Comment: @user287631 а в чем смысл увеличения количества IO-портов?

Comment: Попробуйте поднять ~500 000 сокетов и отправить, а потом принять по одному пакету - на одном IO порту и парочке потоках с GetQueuedCompletionStatus... Как альтернативу, посоветовали AsyncIO, сторонний враппер над IOCP, по предварительным данным она более привычная и гибкая.

Comment: @user287631 вы так пишите, как будто это так просто - взять и поднять свой проактор на IOCP... А ничего что там кода на сто страниц будет?

Comment: @user287631 есть какие-нибудь исследования скорости работы GetQueuedCompletionStatus при большом числе сокетов?

Comment: Исследования есть, но они все касаются нативных реализаций (по RIO, например, встречал хорошие исследования). Но я не встречал ни одного исследования для управляемого кода. Могу сказать лишь со своего опыта, ничем не документированного - что мое приложение, портированное с плюсов на управляемый код - не реализует весь потенциал по колл-ву одновременно работающих сокетов в стандартной .NET реализации. Именно поэтому я задал этот вопрос, чтобы понять причину. Причину, для себя, я нашел. Один IO порт, и несколько (по выбору CLR) потоков с GetQueuedCompletionStatus - не справляются.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить - непонятно как регулировать колл-во потоков с GetQueuedCompletionStatus, скорее всего никак. Все это накладывает хорошие ограничения на серверные приложение с большой нагрузкой.

Comment: @user287631 для начала - стоит посмотреть на функцию [ShouldGrowCompletionPortThreadpool](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L3819) и выяснить, стоит ли вообще регулировать количество потоков...